# MYSQL, batch updating new text link in short description of woo commerce singe shop page

Tags: mysql

[screenshot of the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFdyo.png)

Hi, I have posted hundreds of products, with a link in the short description (product excerpt) in a woocommerce shop.

Now want to update that link with a new link.

which SQL is correct?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,‘href="http://xxx/about">Ordering</a>？‘,
‘href="http://xxxx/ordering guid">Ordering</a>？‘);
```

or

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE (post_excerpt,‘href="http://xxx/about">Ordering</a>？‘,
‘href="http://xxx/ordering guid">Ordering</a>？‘);
```

or what else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Search And Replace` anything from WP Database. Maybe below script can help you.

Here is the link [Database Search and Replace Script in PHP](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

> Note : This is script is only for `Wordpress` Database.

Comment: Hi,  If I change with the plugin and delete the plugin, the changes can be remained? To be honest, I don't like to use Plugin if can be solve in other ways.. But thanks anyway.